# ufw not working on debian

Tags: debian, ip, ufw

I'm trying to install `ufw` on my debian buster machine and get it to work. I already installed it using `apt-get` and if I try to do so again it says

```
> ufw is already the newest version (0.36-1)
```

So it seems to be installed but when typing `ufw status` or any other `ufw` command it says

```
bash: ufw: command not found
```

Am I missing some dependency? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `ufw` is in /usr/sbin. What is you PATH set to?

Comment: This is secure path and accesible by sudoers . If you run sudo it will be availble (if user put in /etc/sudoers)

Comment: ok thanks guys. using sudo seemed to do the trick

Comment: @user3728800 it is not a secure path. It is just a place with stuff that is mostly only useful to root.

Comment: You are right but when normal user Don't hqve access . Its bot secure . You think secure is just firewalled. Im teaching linux and its better somehow easy undertod linux for user

Answer (score 4):

Command should be run by typing

```
sudo ufw <insert option here>
```

Otherwise you will get the error

```
bash: ufw: command not found
```

If all fails restart and reinstall ufw

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to have `/usr/sbin` in your `PATH`:

- Edit your `.profile`:

  ```
  nano ~/.profile
  ```
- Add the following line to bottom of file

  ```
  export PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Re Debian ufw and previous comments:

- `su` first to gain root privileges
- then in `root@enlightened` persona enter

  ```
  sudu ufw enable
  ```

I hadn’t realised one had to sudo after su but it works

```
sudo ufw status
Status: active
```

Answer (score -1):

only use "su -"
and the access to ufw command (and others) will work ok.
with only "su" or logged as Root, dont work.
Best regards!

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please reformulate your post, as it is unclear whether this is an answer or a question.

Comment: It's unclear _why_ this would solve the issue. Consider explaining what the issue is and how this solves it.

Answer (score -1):

While installing debian, it asks for the root name and the username (admin).
Generally, it is usually the same for both in addition to the same password. Other times the name for root is not chosen and that name is taken by default: "root".
If you log in with your username, even if you have administrator privileges, it will not recognize the ufw command.
Try to login as "root".
servername login: root
password: yourpassword